# How does application widget link to application object?

Tags: python, pyside2

I've been checking out [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/widgets.html) PyQt / PySide2 documentation and it lists this example:

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
label = QLabel("Hello World!")
label.show()
app.exec_()
```

In the equivalent `tkinter` code, the widget must be passed a reference to the application to know where to appear:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root) # <-- reference to application passed
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

How does the Qt `label` know which application to reference? It's not global or something?

Comment: Technically speaking, you don't _have_ to pass `root` to `Label` in tkinter. It's a best practice, but strictly speaking it's not required.

Comment: In a typical Qt application, you'll have a QApplication and some kind of QMainWindow. In that case, if you wanted add your label to your QMainWindow, you would do something like 'label = QLabel('my text', parent=mywindow)`. In this case, your main display widget is the QLabel itself and you don't have to declare the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QApplication is a singleton that can be accessed anywhere using QApplication::instance() or qApp (in C++) so it is not passed the object directly to it. I do not know tkinter so I do not know why it is necessary or as [@Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) says a best practice.